# Is there a way to remove Paragraph from the Lyx Navigate menu?

Tags: lyx

In the Navigate menu in Lyx, is there a setting to hide nodes below a certain level? ie. Can I make the navigate menu only show Part and Section and nothing smaller?

I have a lot of Paragraph nodes in the document that are making the Navigate menu an absolute mess and useless. There are depth options for the Outline pane and for the Table of Contents, so it seems like you should be able to reduce the number of node levels shown in the Navigate menu.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I tried but could not figure out how to do this. I read Help > Customization manual, and specifically the entries for "AddToToc", "TocLevel, and "OutlinerName", and experimented with setting values (e.g., setting to empty string, or to 0), and it did not have the intended effect.

Comment: Just curiosity. As you said,  the you can do that easily in the Outline Pane, that is in fact also navigate menu (and more practical, imho). So, why not just use this pane?